# SharePoint 2007 - Possible to show Site Actions for a specific SharePoint group?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Through permission levels (and breaking the list's inherited permissions) we can make it so a small group of users has full control over a list.  Likewise, you can have a small group of authors for this list.

Both of these group could be part of the Visitor group of your site in general so that most of the time the admins just are readers.

The problem I have is that it becomes more difficult to advise those admins of how to navigate to the list which they're supposed to admin.

Site Actions does not show up for groups w/ Limited Access.  Adding manage-site permissions to this group likely allows them to go SiteActions->View All Site Content and then navigate to the list in question however, this would grant them too much site-wide permissions.

I'd thought about putting a Content Editor WebPart on this page and include the list's link... then you can Audience that web part so it only shows up for the admin group.  But im wondering if there may be a more clever way to go about this.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your Sharepoint MasterPage you can add a control an html tag named .  This is a simple control to display or hide content depending on the Sharepoint security.  Just embed the  tag within the SPSecurityTrimmedControl tag then set the PermissionString value to what you need.

Example :

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl2" runat="server" PermissionsString="ManageSubwebs">

    <table height=100% class="ms-siteaction" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
                     <tr>
                           <td class="ms-siteactionsmenu" id="siteactiontd">
                           <SharePoint:SiteActions runat="server" AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,tb_SiteActions_AK%>" id="SiteActionsMenuMain"
                            PrefixHtml="&lt;div&gt;&lt;div&gt;"

    ... ... ...

</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

I wont take all the credit for that, I found the exact answer here :
http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/11/how-to-remove-site-actions-and-view-all.html